# Socket io Multiple Game Rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on a multiplayer chess website with different rooms and connecting two players, all through Socket IO and Node JS something similar to http://www.retichess.com/play/NjUwMS41ODM1SERrSEVt/30/0. As for now it looks like this http://www.group7port2.azurewebsites.net

The problem i'm having is not understanding how to establish the connection between both players as they do on RetiChess and their URL Generation.

Where should I start looking at? Thanks!

Comment: Takes me back to the Yahoo Games days when they had rankings for different games like Chess and Monopoly.

Answer (score 0):

If you read through Socket.IO documentation, you'll learn more about the `Room` concept. There is never such a thing as direct player connection. There is always the server in between.

Sharing an URL allows a player to join another player's room and that's it!

Your job is to be able to send data from one player to the other, while they are in the same socket.IO room!

Comment: Thanks Valentin! I will keep playing around with the NameSpace & Rooms concept.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)